# encoding and decoding program using scheme(java)

Tags: java, string, encoding, decoding

The program should prompt the user to select whether a message is to be encoded or decoded, and then prompts the user to enter the message. A blank space is used to separate each word in the message, and a period (.) is used to denote the end of a sentence. Separate methods must be used to encode and decode the input message.

Scheme: A -> Z, B -> Y, C -> X, .... X -> C, Y -> B, Z -> A

I think everything is ok except the logic on the encode and decode method.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Project1
    {
        public static void main(  String [] args )
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print( "Press 1 for Encoding, 2 for Decoding: " );
            int x = input.nextInt();
            String temp = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print( "Enter message: ");
            String message = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" ");



            if ( x == 1)
            {

                encodeMessage( message );
            }

            else if ( x == 2 )
            {   

                decodeMessage( message );
            }

            else
                System.out.print("Invalid response");

        }


        public static void encodeMessage(String message)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
            {
                char x = message.charAt(i);
                System.out.print((char)(27 - x));

             }
        }


        public static void decodeMessage (String message)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
            {
                char x = message.charAt(i);
                System.out.print((char)(27 - x));

            }
        }


    }
```

When I enter a message, it displays question marks.

Comment: How did you conclude that '27 - x' would convert 'A' to 'Z', for example?

Comment: Tried a debugger?

Comment: i saw an example which used (char)(x + 1) and it displayed the letter right after x. I assumed the code was thinking a = 1, b = 2, c =3... etc. So if the letter was a(which would be 1), i can just do 27 - 1, which would display z. I'm a beginner so sorry if this sounds really dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that char at `(char)(27 - x)` is possible? Because otherwise it will show as question marks or some other symbols, depending on the charset.

For example, the following code:

```java
System.out.println((char)1);
```

Prints out this symbol:

Comment: 27 - 'A' (for example) is -38, which as a 16-bit unsigned (i.e., char) value is 0xffda, or HALFWIDTH HANGUL LETTER EU, which I imagine the OP does not have in his chosen font.

Comment: it displays question marks. is there a code that can be used instead of 27 - x?